# Did a foreigner ever lead a revolution?

Tags: revolution

Foreign powers sometimes sponsor revolutions, but did a foreigner ever voluntary come into a country and lead a revolution there?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: prior research please. Garibaldi comes to mind as does the entire American revolution, William of Orange, Karl Marx, etc. I'm sure others will come to mind, but this question needs prior research and needs a way to choose an authoritative answer

Comment: Do you know who Che Guevera is? If not, google his name.

Comment: What exactly counts as a foreigner? In all the examples mentioned so far it is difficult to say as people often lived in several countries and also national borders can change and don't necessarily reflect ethnicity or any other criteria for defining "foreign".

Comment: @MCW Karl Marx? I'm not sure he falls into the OP's description "come into a country and lead a revolution there".

Comment: @StephanMatthiesen - arguable. I see your point, but he did move to London and lead a worldwide revolution.  That said, the point is carried by other examples and I acknowledge that Martin's answer below is superior to my comment.

Comment: @MCW Sure, it depends on what the OP means by "lead a revolution". I didn't mean to dismiss your point, it's just not how I understood the question. Of course Marx was definitely a philosophical/ideological leader of many revolutions, but he didn't do any of the actual "revolutionising" like fighting and setting up governments.

Comment: Erm, Hitler was an Austrian, the Beer Hall Putsch was an attempt at a revolution.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, for example:

Simón Bolívar was Venezuelan-born and led revolutions both in his native Venezuela and also Colombia, Ecuador, Peru and Bolivia.  The latter being named in his honour.  For further information see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sim%C3%B3n_Bol%C3%ADvar)

Ernesto "Che" Guevara was Argentinian yet led revolutions in Cuba, Congo-Kinshasa and Bolivia.  The latter two were unsuccessful though.  For further information see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Che_Guevara)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Done as requested.

Comment: @Martin Welcome to SE History!

Comment: These are good examples, although for Bolívar it could be argued that these countries were all Spanish colonies, so - in a sense - he wasn't totally a foreigner in any of them. It's tricky how to define countries and nationalities at the time.